# Mysql best students in every class in a school

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql I need to select top student in every class in a school in `termid=10` to get discount for next term enrollment .

Please notice that total is not in table(I put in below for clearing problem)

I have this workbook table for all students workbook:

```
id   studentid   classid   exam1    exam2     total   termid    
1       2          11       20        40       60       10        
2       1          22       40        20       60       10        
3       4          11       40        20       60       10        
4       5          33       10        60       70       10        
5       7          22       10        40       50       10        
6       8          11       10        30       40       10        
7       9          33       20        45       65       10        
8       11         11      null      null     null      10        
9       12         54      null      null     null      02 
10      13         58      null      null     null      02
```

1st challenge is : `exam1` and `exam2` are `VARCHAR` and total is not in table (as i explained).

2nd challenge is : as you can see in `id=8` std #11 has not numbers

3rd challenge is : may be two students have top level so they must be in result.

I need result as :

```
id   studentid   classid   exam1    exam2     total   termid    
1       2          11       20        40       60       10                
3       4          11       40        20       60       10        
4       5          33       10        60       70       10        
2       1          22       40        20       60       10
```

i have this query but not work good as i mention.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,studentid,classid,exam1,exam2,total,termid ,(CAST(exam1 AS DECIMAL(9,2))+CAST(exam2 AS DECIMAL(9,2))) FROM workbook  WHERE ClassId = '10';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to join the table with itself. You find out the max for each class and then join all students of this class which match the class max:

max for each class (included in the final statement already):

```
SELECT classid, MAX(CAST(exam1 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(exam2 AS UNSIGNED)) as 'maxtotal'
          FROM students
          WHERE NOT ISNULL(exam1)
                AND NOT ISNULL(exam2)
          GROUP BY classid
```

The complete statement:

```
SELECT s2.*, s1.maxtotal
FROM (SELECT classid, MAX(CAST(exam1 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(exam2 AS UNSIGNED)) as 'maxtotal'
      FROM students
      WHERE NOT ISNULL(exam1)
            AND NOT ISNULL(exam2)
      GROUP BY classid) s1
JOIN students s2 ON s1.classid = s2.classid
WHERE s1.maxtotal = (CAST(s2.exam1 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(s2.exam2 AS UNSIGNED));
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f117/1

Comment: Damn, have been too slow typing ;-) Good job Gordon, also with the coalesce to return zero if value is null.

Comment: If i want to have result only for termid='10' what i must to do ?

Comment: Yhou have to add "AND termid=10"/"AND s1.termid=10" to both WHERE clauses. In this way the MAX is calculated from term 10 only and also only the students from term 10 are joined.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total for the students by just adding the values (MySQL will convert the values to numbers).  The following gets the max total for each class:

```
select w.classid, max(coalesce(w.exam1, 0) + coalesce(w.exam2, 0)) as maxtotal
from workbook w
group by w.classid;
```

You can then `join` this back to the original data to get information about the best students:

```
select w.*, coalesce(w.exam1, 0) + coalesce(w.exam2, 0) as total
from workbook w join
     (select w.classid, max(coalesce(w.exam1, 0) + coalesce(w.exam2, 0)) as maxtotal
      from workbook w
      group by w.classid
     ) ww
     on w.classid = ww.classid and (coalesce(w.exam1, 0) + coalesce(w.exam2, 0)) = ww.maxtotal;
```

Comment: @ms . . . That was a missing alias.  It is there now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Group by Statement:

```
SELECT 
    studentid,
    classid,
    max(coalesce(exam1,0)) as max_exam_1,
    max(coalesce(exam2,0)) as max_exam_2,
    sum(coalesce(exam1,0) + coalesce(exam2,0)) as sum_exam_total,
    termid
FROM 
    workbook  
WHERE 
    termid=10
GROUP BY 
    1,2
ORDER BY 
    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id,studentid,classid,exam1,exam2,(CAST(exam1 AS DECIMAL(9,2))+CAST(exam2 AS DECIMAL(9,2))) AS total,termid FROM `workbook` WHERE ((CAST(exam1 AS DECIMAL(9,2))+CAST(exam2 AS DECIMAL(9,2)))) > 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all my friends

I think combine between 2 answer in above is best :

```
SELECT s2.*, s1.maxtotal
FROM (SELECT ClassId, MAX(
coalesce(exam1,0)+
coalesce(exam2,0)
) as 'maxtotal'
      FROM workbook
      WHERE
      (
 termid = '11'
      )
      GROUP BY ClassId) s1
JOIN workbook s2 ON s1.ClassId = s2.ClassId
WHERE s1.maxtotal = (
coalesce(exam1,0)+
coalesce(exam2,0)
) AND (s1.maxtotal >'75');
```

last line is good for s1.maxtotal=0 (some times student scores have not be entered and all  equals 0 so all will shown as best students) or some times we need minimum score (to enroll in next term).

So thanks all